# How do I solve this equation $ \sin(x) = \sin(\frac{11}{9}\pi)$?

Tags: trigonometry

We are supposed to use this formula for which I can't find any explaination anywhere and our teacher didn't explain anything so if anyone could help me I would appreciate it.

$ x = A + k \times 2\pi$

and

$x = \pi - A + k \times 2\pi$

where $k$ is supposed to be a random integer? and A in this case is $\frac{11}{9}\pi$

Comment: Apply http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html on $\sin x=\sin11\pi/9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is always the same:

## DRAW A DIAGRAM!

It doesn't need to be a particularly precise diagram -- we're not going to measure anything on it, just get an overview of how things fit together. Here's a rough graph of $\sin(x)$ with $x=\frac{11}{9}\pi$ marked:

[image: graph of sin(1)]

$\frac{11}{9}\pi$ is a bit more than $\pi$, so the value of $\sin \frac{11}{9}$ is somewhere between $-1$ and $0$. We need to find all the $x$ that have that value as their sine.

[image: graph with solutions marked]

$x=\frac{11}{9}\pi$ itself is certainly one solution. And we know that the sine repeats itself with a period of $2\pi$, so $x=\frac{11}{9}\pi+2\pi$ is another solution, and $\frac{11}{9}\pi+2\pi+2\pi$ is yet another one, and so forth, and to the other side $\frac{11}{9}\pi-2\pi = -\frac{7}{9}\pi$ is also a solution, and *so* forth. This gives us
$$ x = \frac{11}{9}\pi + 2k\pi, k\in\mathbb Z, $$
the points indicated in green here:

[image: graph with descending points marked]

These are all the points where the sine curve passes *down* through the red horizontal line. We're still missing the ones where the curve crosses back *up* again, but we can figure out where they are because the sine curve is mirror symmetric about each of it throughs and crests. So the first *up* crossing after $x=0$ is just as far *left* of $2\pi$ as our known *down* crossing is *right* of $\pi$, and we get for this point
$$ x = 2\pi - (\frac{11}{9}\pi - \pi) = \frac{16}{9}\pi $$
This point also has copies at regular $2\pi$ intervals to the right, so this gives the blue solutions
$$ x = \frac{16}{9}\pi + 2k\pi, k\in\mathbb Z $$

[image: diagram with even more markings]

The **complete** solution is $$ x = \begin{cases} \frac{11}{9}\pi + 2k\pi & k\in\mathbb Z \\ \frac{16}9 \pi + 2k\pi & k \in\mathbb Z \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have the arcsine function has a range of $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, but sine is negative in both quadrants $3$ and $4$, so only the quadrant $4$ angle is returned. (The opposite is also true: sine is positive in both quadrant $1$ and $2$, but only the quadrant $1$ angle is returned.) Also note that $\sin(\pi-\theta) = \sin(\theta)$.

Hence, we have

$$\sin (x) = y \implies x = \begin{cases}\ \arcsin y+2\pi k \\ \pi-\arcsin y+2\pi k\end{cases}; \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

So, if $$\sin(x) = \sin\left(\frac{11}{9}\pi\right)$$

then there are two cases:

$$x = \begin{cases}\ \frac{11}{9}\pi+2\pi k \\ \pi-\frac{11}{9}\pi+2\pi k\end{cases}$$

with the first being for angles in quadrant $3$ and the second being for angles in quadrant $4$.

---

As for why we have $2\pi k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($k$ must be an integer), this is because trig functions are periodic. Note that since $2\pi$ (or $360°$) represents one full revolution, you return back to where you started. For example, $\frac{9\pi}{4}$ radians would mean $2\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$, so it’s represents the same angle as $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So, any two angles separated by $2\pi$, $4\pi$, $6\pi$, ... radians actually represent the same angle. (In degrees, that would be $360°$, $720°$, $1080°$, etc.) So, we generalize this as all integer multiples of $2\pi$ radians or $360°$.

As a simple example, assume we have $\sin(x) = 1$. Clearly, the answer must be $\pi$. But $\pi+2\pi$ also works. So does $\pi-2\pi$. So does any angle $2\pi k$ radians apart from $\pi$. So we would generalize the answer and give the full solution as $\pi+2\pi k$, as they all represent the same angle, a right angle. In other words, there are infinite solutions.

However, you may occasionally be given a restricted domain such as $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$. Then, you include only the angles in the four quadrants. (In the example you gave, you omit the $2\pi k$ for both cases, and in the example I gave, the answer simply becomes $\pi$.)

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies a bit but our teacher didn't say anything about arcsin. This is all we got - https://i.imgur.com/f8BNPwi.png

Comment: Arcsine is the inverse of sine. (I guess you’re given examples which do not involve irregular angles.) You can simply cancel the sines and obtain $\frac{11}{9}\pi+2\pi k$ for the first case and then use the identity $\sin(\pi-\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ to obtain the second case. I was guessing you’ve studied it, but it’s certainly not required here.

Comment: Also, when you have $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$, the cases simplify to $x = \begin{cases} x= y+2\pi k \\ x = \pi-y+2\pi k \end{cases}$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have equation $\sin x=a$, the solutions are $x=\arcsin a +2\pi n$ and $x=\pi-\arcsin a + 2\pi n$. This is based on the identity $\sin(\pi-a)=\sin a$. In your case $a=\sin(\frac{11\pi}{9})$ so the solutions are $x=\arcsin(\sin(\frac{11\pi}{9}))+2\pi n=-\frac{2\pi}{9}+2\pi n$ and $x=\pi-\arcsin(\sin(\frac{11\pi}{9}))+2\pi n=\frac{11\pi}{9}+2\pi n$. Term $2\pi n$ is added becase sine is $2 \pi$ periodic thus $\sin(a+2\pi n)=\sin(a)$